# How to add multiple include file names under NAMES while using FIND_PATH in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake, wildcard, filepath

I am trying to include several header files under NAMES while using FIND_PATH, was wondering if there was a way to include them without specifying each one of them.

Currently i use below format for this purpose.

```
FIND_PATH(FILE_INCLUDE
NAMES "xyz/x.h"
      "xy/y.h"
      ......
      ...... 
PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
PATH_SUFFIXES xy/yx/xyz
NO_DEFAULT_PATH
NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
)
```

I was wondering if there was a easier way to specify the list of NAMES as there are lot to be added.

Comment: Collect names in some variable (as list) and dereference this variable when needed. When dereference list variable, quotes shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

> CMake provides the following command for recursive files globing:
>
> file(GLOB_RECURSE variable [RELATIVE path]     [FOLLOW_SYMLINKS]
>   [globbing expressions]...) Command documentation:
>   http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:file

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look at this.